# getting body with express busboy

Tags: node.js, express, busboy

I am trying to use busboy middleware to get the body from a POST request.

I have the following in the main server.js

```
//file upload middleware
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
app.use(busboy());
```

I have a route set up like so:

```
app.post('/create', function(req, res){

    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('finish', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log(req.body);
    });

});
```

But if I send a request to the endpoint i get the following error:

```
_stream_readable.js:501
    dest.end();
         ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'end' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:501:10)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

How can I read the body inside of this route?

Answer (score 2):

Your `finish` event handler is wrong. It looks like a typo and should be a `file` event handler instead.

Secondly, it looks like the request's `Content-Type` is not correct. It should either be `multipart/form-data` either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Lastly, `req.body` will not be set inside your event handler because you're not populating it, so that will always be `undefined`.